# Understanding Variational inference for LDA

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc, variational-inference

I am trying to derive from scratch variational inference for LDA. I am following this course: [https://home.cs.colorado.edu/~jbg/teaching/CSCI_5622/19a.pdf](https://home.cs.colorado.edu/%7Ejbg/teaching/CSCI_5622/19a.pdf)

When computing $p(Z|\Theta)$ they do the following:
[image]

What I can't understand is where does that $\Phi_{ni}$ comes from. $\Phi$ is supposed to be the parameters of the variational distribution of Z, so why it is there??
For those who are familiar with the original paper of LDA (Blei 2003) https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/blei03a/blei03a.pdf ,
I faced the same problem in the appendix when they were computing the ELBO

Comment: it's cause $\mathbb{E}_q[\log\theta_i^{\mathbb{I}[z_n==i]}] = \mathbb{E}_q[\mathbb{I}[z_n==i] \log\theta_i] =\mathbb{E}_q[\mathbb{I}[z_n==i]] \mathbb{E}_{q}[\log\theta_i] = \phi_{n,i}\mathbb{E}_{q}[\log\theta_i] $.

Comment: Why the $E_q[I[z_n==i]] = \Phi_{n,i}$?

Comment: That's the definition of $\phi_{n,i}$; $z_n$ is categorical with parameter vector $\Phi$ (variationally).

Comment: I get it know thank you.